# I'm trying to implement group by on a table and want to implement it from repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've a table tbl_rating, I'm trying to get avg o=rating of the users that are existing in this table. 
This is the table I have.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `contact` (`contact`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is the tbl_rating

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_rating` (
  `id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `point` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is the query that I'm trying to implement from repository.

```
SELECT r.user_id, u.name, AVG(r.point) AS average
FROM tbl_rating r LEFT JOIN tbl_user u ON u.id=r.user_id
GROUP BY r.user_id;
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/rating/avg/individual", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public JsonNode getAvgRatingOfIndividual(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws IOException {

        JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

        List<Rating> ratings = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            ratings = ratingService.getAvgRatingOfIndividual();

            if (ratings.size() > 0) {

            } else {
                response = new JSONArray();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return objectMapper.readTree(utility.createResponse(500, KeyWord.ERROR, e.toString()).toString());
        }

        return objectMapper.readTree(response.toString());
    }
```

following are the service and repository where I'm stuck
service

```
public List<Rating> getAvgRatingOfIndividual() {
        return ratingRepository.??
    }
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends JpaRepository<Rating, Long> {
}
```

rating model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_rating")
public class Rating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @Column(name = "point")
    int point;

    @Column(name = "status")
    String status;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(int point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

user model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;

    @Column(name = "contact")
    String contact;

    @Column(name = "status")
    String status;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}
```

would appreciate if i could get any sort of help on this native query writing in spring boot repository

Comment: Please show the `Rating` class too

Comment: Sir, added the tbl_rating.

Comment: Not table, I mean the java code please

Comment: added both user and rating

Comment: It seems you don't try much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721884/i-want-to-get-average-of-every-user-id-in-a-table-table-contains-same-user-id-f. What have you tried? What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use from a DTO and fill it implicitly in repository.

```java
package com.test.dto;

@Value
public class RatingDTO{
  private Long userId;
  private String name;
  private Double average;
}
```

And in the repository class:

```java
//RatingRepository.java
@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends JpaRepository<Rating, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT new com.test.dto.RatingDTO(R.user.id, R.user.name, AVG(R.point)) FROM Rating R GROUP BY R.user.id")
  List<RatingDTO> getAveragePoints();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I was on the same track with the dedicated object but you also optimize the request on one table. And faster as well :-)

Comment: @XavierBouclet Thanks. Actually there is one request on one model but a joining on tables are done underneath

Comment: I've followed another way but not being able to put customized response, would you please take a look?

Comment: ` @Query("SELECT r.user, AVG(r.rating) FROM Rating r group by r.user")
    List<Rating> findAllRatings();`

I'm getting the output but can not modify it

Comment: @SubhaBhowmik Are you sure you got output by the query you mentioned?

Comment: yep, a bit different table though, not the one I mentioned here.